# Terraform for Firestore creation

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, terraform

is it possible to automate GCP Firestore creation using Terraform or another tool? I cannot find anything about it in docs.
Regards

Answer (score 7):

See https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/solutions/automate-database-create#create_a_database_with_terraform

Set the database_type to CLOUD_FIRESTORE or CLOUD_DATASTORE_COMPATIBILITY.

```
provider "google" {
  credentials = file("credentials-file")
}

resource "google_project" "my_project" {
  name = "My Project"
  project_id = "project-id"
}

resource "google_app_engine_application" "app" {
  project     = google_project.my_project.project_id
  location_id = "location"
  database_type = "CLOUD_FIRESTORE"
}
```

Comment: the google cloud sdk can manage credentials for you in most cases. just use the `gcloud auth login` bash command and follow the instructions. After that, you won't need to create a credentials file and use `credentials=file("credentials-file")`

Comment: This is not currently working. Getting `An argument named "database_type" is not expected here.`

Answer (score 1):

Update 7/23/20: see [automating database creation](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/solutions/automate-database-create).

You can enable Firestore using the [google_project_service](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/google/r/google_project_service.html) resource:

```
resource "google_project_service" "firestore" {
  project = var.project_id
  service = "firestore.googleapis.com"

  disable_dependent_services = true
}
```

Edit: I don't see any possibility to create the database itself, however, you can use the [google_firebase_project_location](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/google/r/firebase_project_location.html) to set the location of the Firestore (this will also set the GAE location and the location of the default bucket).

Comment: Thank you. But I'm not sure if I can configure Firestore from here e.g. select zone, Database name and Datastore compatibility mode

Comment: No. Now I can only enable service, but I'm unable to create database instance with desired configuration

Answer (score 1):

As of v4.56.0, there is now a [`google_firestore_database`](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/solutions/automate-database-create#create_a_database_with_terraform) resource available in the Terraform Google Provider. You can create a new firestore database like this:

```
resource "google_firestore_database" "database" {
  project     = google_project.my_project.project_id
  name        = "(default)"
  location_id = "location"
  type        = "FIRESTORE_NATIVE"

  depends_on = [google_project_service.firestore]
}
```